# error while installing python-mcrypt-1.1 in virtual env - fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install python-mcrypt-1.1 with below command

```
pip install http://labix.org/download/python-mcrypt/python-mcrypt-1.1.tar.gz
```

but i am getting below error i have tried with sudo permission as well but not able to install and getting below error

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'mcrypt' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DVERSION="1.1" -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mcrypt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mcrypt.o
mcrypt.c:23:20: fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mcrypt.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution for this issue .
For mcrypt.h, libmcrypt-dev needs to install by following command

```
sudo apt-get install libmcrypt-dev
```

after installing with above command python-crypt got install successfully with below command

```
pip install http://labix.org/download/python-mcrypt/python-mcrypt-1.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

python-mcrypt is a Python interface to the mcrypt library. You have to install [mcrypt](http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/) first.

Comment: i already tried installing the mcrypt but is giving below error 

No matching distribution found for mcrypt

commad used - pip install mcrypt

Comment: `pip install mcrypt` is not a command to install `mcrypt`, it's a command to install `python-mcrypt` wrapper. You have to install mcrypt from http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/